# Async piping file to an HTTP request

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, stream, npm-request

I'm trying to send off interleaved GET and POST requests to a server, but the POST request is sending data from a file, which seems to throw off the timing.

```
var async = require('async');
var http = require('http');
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

var arr = [];
for (var i = 1; i <= 50; i++) {
   arr.push(i);
}

var limitedAgent = new http.Agent({maxSockets: 6});

function processThenSendRequest(data, onfinish) {
    request.get({
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        pool: limitedAgent
    }, (function(j) {
        return function(err, res) {
            console.log("GET: response from " + j);
        };
    })(data)).on('socket', (function(j) {
        return function(socket) {
            console.log("GET: socket assigned for " + j);
        }
    })(data));

    var source = fs.createReadStream('README.md');

    var postReq = request.post({
        url: 'http://www.google.com',
        pool: limitedAgent
    }, (function(j) {
        return function(err, res) {
            console.log("POST: response from " + j);
        };
    })(data)).on('socket', (function(j) {
        return function(socket) {
            console.log("POST: socket assigned for " + j);
        }
        })(data));

    // source.pipe(postReq);

    setTimeout(function() {
        onfinish(null, data);
    }, 10000);
}

async.map(arr, processThenSendRequest, function(err, results) {
    if (err) console.error(err);
    console.log("finished");
});
```

The code as written above runs fine, with the GET and POST requests being sent out in alternating order, but if I uncomment the `source.pipe(postReq)` line, then all the GET requests are sent before all the POST requests.

Is there a solution to this issue? I could use `async.mapLimit` but that feels like a hack and that the solution should be through the request library - this impression may be based on a misunderstanding though.

Comment: Because Node is entirely non-blocking (at least when written this way) you can't be sure anything will occur in order unless you run it in series. `async.series` can also do this for you, or `async.eachSeries`.

Comment: This is unrelated, but the extra closures in `processThenSendRequest` that bind `data` are unnecessary because `data` is already scoped to `processThenSendRequest` and the value won't change for that invocation.

Comment: @mscdex Thanks for pointing that out - that makes sense and is a helpful point for me.

Comment: @remus Got it - that makes sense. In that case, I'll use `async.mapLimit` for what I'm doing, since I don't need it to be perfectly in series, but your comment helps clarify what's going on for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per my comment:

> Because Node is entirely non-blocking (at least when written this way) you can't be sure anything will occur in order unless you run it in series. `async.series` can also do this for you, or `async.eachSeries`.

Further to that, since Node doesn’t wait for asynchronous activities to finish, each task gets queued up immediately, while the callbacks (the event completion event) will occur on a first-come-first-serve basis. In your case, since GET requests take far less time to go around than POST requests, that's why they're completing first.